# Python print the same timestamp the same anywhere

Tags: python, time

I'm given a timestamp in seconds, and I 'inherited' a function to print it in human-readable form, but the function is locale-specific; that is, it matters what time zone the host is configured for.  I want to print that time as GMT no matter what time zone I'm in.  For example, here's the sequence on a computer in Mountain Time (the value 315878400 is a 'magic number'):

```
>>> import time
>>> secs = 1308512779
>>> tmp = secs + 315878400
>>> print(time.ctime(tmp))
Tue Jun 22 13:46:19 2021
```

And here it is on a computer in Pacific Time:

```
>>> import time
>>> secs = 1308512779
>>> tmp = secs + 315878400
>>> print(time.ctime(tmp))
Tue Jun 22 12:46:19 2021
```

Given the same time in seconds I'd like to run the same code anywhere and get the same string for output.  Since I don't control the source of the seconds data itself, it's acceptable to assume it's GMT.  Everything I find on the Web is about how to get my local time now, and that's not what this is about.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Python makes it very easy to get datetime objects from Unix time!

```py
from datetime import datetime

def convert(timestamp):
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)

print(convert(1308512779))
# prints: 2011-06-19 19:46:19
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!